# Django formset apparently only printing first form in template (because of invalid markup)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

[**Edit:** See my answer below - the origin of this issue is invalid markup, and browsers working very hard to hide that. ]

I have a formset which *definitely* should contain two forms, but for whatever reason, I am only getting one form printed in the template.

This is the template line:

```
<tr id="existing_docs_row"><td colspan="2">{{ existing_articles.management_form }}{% for f in existing_articles %}<div>{{ f }}</div>{% endfor %}</td></tr>
```

I get the exact same behaviour (less div tags) with:

```
<tr id="existing_docs_row"><td colspan="2">{{ existing_articles }}}</td></tr>
```

The management form and first form are created, but not the second. This is what I get in my browser:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="2" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS"><input type="hidden" id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="2" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS"><input type="hidden" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS"><div><div class="selected_row " id="selected_row"><span class="formlabel"></span><ul>
<li><label for="id_form-0-selected_0"><input type="radio" name="form-0-selected" value="True" id="id_form-0-selected_0"> </label></li>
</ul></div>
<div class="original_filename_row " id="original_filename_row"><span class="formlabel"><span id="for-id_form-0-original_filename-">Original filename:</span></span><div id="id_form-0-original_filename" name="form-0-original_filename">FakeExampleCompanyName.docx</div></div>
<div class="tags_row " id="tags_row"><span class="formlabel"><span id="for-id_form-0-tags-">Tags:</span></span><div id="id_form-0-tags" name="form-0-tags" class="tagarea"><span class="tagitem">England and Wales</span> <span class="tagitem">Private company limited by shares</span> <span class="tagitem">Model articles with amendments</span></div></div>
```

Breaking in the view, and printing the formset shows that it contains two forms (`existing_template_formset` is the name of the formset inside the view):

```
>>> print existing_template_formset <input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="2" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="2" id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" /> 
<div id="selected_row" class="selected_row "> <span class="formlabel"></span><ul> <li><label for="id_form-0-selected_0"><input type="radio" id="id_form-0-selected_0" value="True" name="form-0-selected" /> </label></li> </ul></div> <div id="original_filename_row" class="original_filename_row "><span class="formlabel"><span id="for-id_form-0-original_filename-">Original filename:</span></span><div name="form-0-original_filename" id="id_form-0-original_filename">FakeExampleCompanyName.docx</div></div> <div id="tags_row" class="tags_row "><span class="formlabel"><span id="for-id_form-0-tags-">Tags:</span></span><div class="tagarea" name="form-0-tags" id="id_form-0-tags" ><span class="tagitem" >England and Wales</span> <span class="tagitem" >Private company limited by shares</span> <span class="tagitem" >Model articles with amendments</span></div></div> <tr><th></th><td><input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" id="id_form-0-id" /></td></tr> 
<div id="selected_row" class="selected_row "><span class="formlabel"></span><ul> <li><label for="id_form-1-selected_0"><input type="radio" id="id_form-1-selected_0" value="True" name="form-1-selected" /> </label></li> </ul></div> <div id="original_filename_row" class="original_filename_row "><span class="formlabel"><span id="for-id_form-1-original_filename-">Original filename:</span></span><div name="form-1-original_filename" id="id_form-1-original_filename" >FakeExampleCompanyName.docx</div></div> <div id="tags_row" class="tags_row "><span class="formlabel"><span id="for-id_form-1-tags-">Tags:</span></span><div class="tagarea" name="form-1-tags" id="id_form-1-tags" ></div></div> <tr><th></th><td><input type="hidden" name="form-1-id" id="id_form-1-id" /></td></tr>

>>> len(existing_template_formset) 2
```

As you can see, in both cases, the total number of forms in the formset is 2 (as evidenced in the management form), but the second one is simply not generated.

**Has anyone come across this before? How do I fix this?**

I'm using django 1.3.1 on python 2.7.2 on windows.

For completeness, here is the code which creates the formset:

```
class ExistingTemplateFormset(modelformset_factory(ArticlesTemplate, extra = 0, form=ExistingTemplateForm)):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExistingTemplateFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for x in self:
            x.fields['id'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

            x.fields['original_filename'].editable = False
            x.fields['original_filename'].widget = SpanWidget(tag = u'div')


            x.fields['tags'].widget= TagArea()
            x.fields['tags'].help_text = u''
```

(`TagArea` and `SpanWidget` exist)

In the view:

```
existing_template_formset = ExistingTemplateFormset(queryset = the_organisation.get_template_articles())
```

Comment: where do you define `existing_articles`, is it the same as `exisiting_template_formset`?

Comment: @j_syk: "(`existing_template_formset` is the name of the formset inside the view):"

Comment: Can you try `{{ myformset.as_p }}` or `{% for form in myformset %} {{ form.as_p }} {% endfor %}` ?

Comment: It's very bizarre the print statement is generating 2 forms but not the template.

Comment: yes, I saw that, so you renamed it as you passed it to template? I realize you figured out your problem, just was trying to clarify how you are defining/passing your template variables.

Comment: @j_syk: Yes. Given the explanation in the text, I don't think that's especially mysterious.

Answer (score 2):

Sharp-eyed readers (which, it turns out, does not include me, hence this problem) will note that my output includes at the end of each form:

```
`<tr><th></th><td><input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" id="id_form-0-id" /></td></tr>`
```

Now, when that is substituted into `<tr id="existing_docs_row"><td colspan="2">{{ existing_articles.management_form }}{% for f in existing_articles %}<div>{{ f }}</div>{% endfor %}</td></tr>` that leads to invalid markup (a `tr` inside a `tr`!).

So, it turns out that the template *was* generating the second form, but the browser's error recovery methods (in chrome, disregarding a lot of the invalid markup; in firefox, floating the second form to elsewhere in the DOM) created the appearance that the second form wasn't being generated.

To summarise: just examining the DOM mislead me. Try to force your browser to choke on errors, and look at the raw markup.